# Copy contents of div to replace content in another div

Tags: jquery, append

A snippet of my existing code. I am copying the contents of each "show" div into the "results" div. I have two problems with it - firstly I have to click the radio button twice in order for this to fire. Secondly I want to replace the contents of the "results" div rather than appending. I tried .html but no joy.

```
if(bShouldElementShow){
 jQueryitem.fadeIn();
 jQuery('.show').clone().contents().appendTo('.results').wrap( "<div class='new'></div>" );
}
else {
 jQueryitem.hide();
}
```

Comment: can you share html with complete code?

Comment: Sorry, no. The content is massive and this is a small part of the script. But essentially I just need it to replace the contents in the div.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want like it:-

Here is two `divs` and one button when you click on button then `.div1` content be replicate in `.div2`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('body').on('click', 'button', function(){

    $('.loop').each(function(index, elem){
      var div1Content = $(elem).find('.div1').html();
      $(elem).find('.div2').html(div1Content);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <button>replace content</button>    <br><br>


<div class="loop">
<div class="div1">This is first div -- loop 1</div>
<div class="div2">this is second div -- loop 1</div>
</div>

<br>
<div class="loop">
    <div class="div1">This is first div -- loop 2</div>
    <div class="div2">this is second div -- loop 2</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks - but how do I loop through all divs named div1 in this example?

Comment: which div will be in loop?

Comment: In your example div1 - I have multiple div1 div classes and want to add them all to another div using .html

Comment: @VI_au You need to use each function, like i updated my code in answer, please check again its working fine with loop.